# how to get id in url and display it in a form laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

i have this href that leads you to addeditvisit/.(the chosen row's id)

```
<td><a href="{{ URL::to('addeditvisit/'.$patient->pID) }}"><img src="images/visit.png" style="width:30px; height:30px;"></a></td>
```

so the url looks something like this http://localhost:8000/addeditvisit/5

and inside it is a form. where i want to include the $patient->pID and make it a value of my hidden input so that i can include it saving the form.

in my controller I coded this:

```
$uri = $request->path();
return View::make('pages.addeditvisit', ['uri'=>$uri]);
```

in my form i have this input text first instead of hidden to display what really is the value and it is displays

```
addeditvisit/5
```

what i really want is to only get the 5. what function should i use? Please help me, i'm just new in Laravel 5 and still learning

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your whole Patient object if you want, like this:

```
$patient = Patient::find($id);  // get it from db, or some other data source  
return View::make('pages.addeditvisit', ['uri'=>$uri, 'patient' => $patient]);
```

`
and then in your form you can use the

```
$patient->pID
```

or you can just pass the id itself, if you want to have only that:

```
return View::make('pages.addeditvisit', ['uri'=>$uri, 'pID' => $patient->pID]);
```